# Submanifold of real projective space

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, projective-space

Would you like to tell me how to prove that $\{[x_{0}:x_{1}:x_{2}]: x_{0}x_{1} + x_{2}^{2} = 0 \} \subset \mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2}$ is a submanifold (of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2}$)?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to say $x_0x_1+x_2^2=0$. Let $V$ be that subset. Consider $U_0=\{[x_0,x_1,x_2],x_0\neq 0\}$ define $f([x_0,x_1,x_2])={x_1\over x_0}+{x_2^2\over x_0^2}$ is a submersion on $U_0$ this shows that $V\cap U_0$ is a submanifold.

Comment: Thanks! I found the proposition $f:\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ smooth and $q\in\mathbb{R}$ a regular value $\implies f^{-1}(q)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^{2}$. Is this what you are using?

Comment: @Tsemo Aristide How is the $T_{p}U_{0}$?